# 2D structure of molecule: view.molecule.2d error

Tags: r, rjava, chemistry

```
library(rcdk)
m1 <- parse.smiles('C1CCCC1(C)C')[[1]]
m2 <- parse.smiles('C1CCC(C)CC1')[[1]]

## MCS depends on ordering of input ?!

mcs12 <- get.mcs(m1,m2)
mcs21 <- get.mcs(m2,m1)

view.molecule.2d(c(m1, m2, mcs12, mcs21))
```

I am getting error

> Error in .jnew("org/guha/rcdk/view/ViewMolecule2DTable", array, as.integer(ncol),  :
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: **

In addition to the above is their any package or functions to get the molecular graph of a Chemical structure in hydrogen depleted form

Comment: Hi vs! It looks like other people have have similar issues before, as you can see [on GitHub](https://github.com/CDK-R/cdkr/issues?q=is%3Aissue+java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)
Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes I am using windows system so how else can I solve the issuse is their any other package which can help me similar rcdk functionalities